# Is there a way to configure eclipse that it treats gss files like css files?

Tags: html, css, eclipse, code-completion, google-closure-stylesheet

I want to enable eclipse specific code completion and syntax highlighting for css to files that ends with gss. The gss files are similar to css files. They are called [closure-stylesheets](https://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/).

**Is there a way to configure eclipse that it treats gss files like css files to get code completion enabled?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For individual files you can just right click on the file and select 'Open With > CSS editor' (this will be remembered for future editing)

To set for all files go to 'Preferences > General > Content Types'. Find 'CSS' under 'Text' and click 'Add...' to add a '*.gss' association.